# VSC Prolog on MacOS Mojave error: "path to executable was not found"

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, prolog

I installed the VSC Prolog extension for Visual Studio code on MacOS Mojave. I get this error:

```
Cannot lint the prolog file. The Prolog executable was not found. Use the 'prolog.executablePath' setting to configure
```

In the settings for VSC Prolog i set the path to the executable to:

```
/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS/swipl
```

I got this by typing `which swipl` in Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

`Cmd Shift P`(or windows alternative on VSCode)

Then type in

> settings.json

Open up the settings.json file. Currently the README in the SWI-Prolog dmg says the directory to add to `$PATH` if installed in Applications is

> "/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS"

Therefore add the following line to your settings.json file

```
    "prolog.executablePath": "/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS"
```

Save the file and restart VSCode, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The path that finally worked for me is /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS/swipl

Comment: I found that in Windows the path is C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\swipl-win.exe

Answer (score 0):

To add info to the up answer, if you installed with Homebrew, the path probably is "/usr/local/opt/swi-prolog/bin/swipl"